# StackOverflowError: null in Android Studio on Project Structure

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Ever since I updated to Android Studio 2.3, there is an IDE error in some cases: for example when I click `File->Project Structure`, try to open any layout XML, or even click any point in the code of any `build.gradle` file (these at least open without exceptions). The error says `StackOverflowError: null`, and the stack trace is the same in all cases:

```
null
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2079)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1696)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2223)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.settings.ProjectPropertiesDslElement.getStandardProjectKey(ProjectPropertiesDslElement.java:52)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslExpression.resolveProjectReference(GradleDslExpression.java:191)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslExpression.resolveReference(GradleDslExpression.java:92)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslReference.getValue(GradleDslReference.java:66)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslExpression.resolveReference(GradleDslExpression.java:152)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslReference.getValue(GradleDslReference.java:66)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dsl.parser.elements.GradleDslExpression.resolveReference(GradleDslExpression.java:152)
```

... and the last 2 lines repeat forever.

**What can I do to find the source of this problem?**

It looks like there's a circular reference somewhere in my build configs, or the internals of Studio? But I can't find any by hand. It would be helpful if I at least knew what's the pattern or the reference mentioned in the stack trace.

Things I already tried:

- invalidate cache & restart
- delete `.idea/` and other temporary folders in project directory
- check out the project to a new location
- in `settings->build->gradle->experimental` enable the "new Project Structure dialog" -- then the dialog works, but the same error still occurs upon closing it, and other cases still don't work

I'm using Android Studio 2.3.3 with all the plugins and android libs updated, gradle 3.3 and gradle plugin 2.3.1; all that on an up-to-date gentoo linux.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved the issue. There were these 3 lines in my main `build.gradle`:

```
ext.kotlinVersion = kotlinVersion
ext.supportLibVersion = supportLibVersion
ext.playServicesVersion = playServicesVersion
```

In this project the `*Version` variables are assigned in `gradle.properties` file, not in `build.gradle` files, so they're already accessible in all module gradle files, and the lines above create a circular reference. (I'm no expert on gradle, that's just a guess)

I think they were added by the Kotlin plugin at some point (the "configure Kotlin in project" option), and the automated edit messed up our complicated configs. Or some previous dev left it there. I can't seem to reproduce it on a clean project.